# Move file after processing

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have the following loop which works accept for the move file part

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(dir, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.csv")
            ''If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastFile)) Then
            ''File.Move(Path.GetFullPath(lastFile), (dir + "/processed/"))
            ''End If

            Dim oTimer As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
            oTimer.Start()
            Dim tblName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(foundFile)
            Dim numbers() As Char = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"}
            tblName = tblName.TrimEnd(numbers)
            ''analyze table name, call method for either insert or append

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@tblName", tblName))
            ''this command should check the table to exist first, but need to add if
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            retRecCnt += insertRows(conString, foundFile, tblName)
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            lastFile = foundFile
            ''
        Next
```

It properly exports the CSV file to the database table and moves on to the next file.  but when the move command is called I get the following error:

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024864
  Message=The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
  Source=mscorlib
```

Comment: Most likely you haven't closed whatever connection object you used to process the file.  You'll need to close that connection to release the lock.

Comment: most likely `insertRows` is to blame by not playing nice and closing and releasing things

Comment: @tim can you give me some guidance on how to close that connect?

Comment: @MKasper - It's hard to give an accurate fix, as it's not clear from your code where the connection is being established.  Can you post the `insertRows` code?